# Issue Iterating Regex Match Tuples Into Rows Within Excel File

Tags: python-3.x, loops, openpyxl

After researching on Stack Overflow and the web alike, I cannot find a solution to the intricacies of my question and thus I am asking it here. My goal is to iterate the results of a 5 part tuple per regex match into Excel rows one after each other (one row for each set of matches; columns stay the same) using openpyxl. The excerpted code is as follows:

```
match = re.findall(pattern, inputfile.read())
if match:
    for tuple in match:
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value = tuple[0]
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value = tuple[1]
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=3).value = tuple[2]
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=4).value = tuple[3]
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=5).value = tuple[4]
```

However, the issue I am having is that I cannot find a way to move onto the next row for the next match. What my code is doing is just writing and then rewriting row 2 with each new match (it starts on row 2 as row 1 is the header). I tried using arithmetic operators (like + 1) to advance the row for a new match, but all this does is move the writing/overwriting process down by one.

How can I fix this piece of code so that each new match (with its 5 part tuple) is inserted on a new row and doesn't overwrite the previously inserted match? Thank you!

P.S. I am new to Stack Overflow, so if I am asking questions improperly in contrast to the norm, please let me know (+ ways I can fix them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openpyxl defaults to adding rows below the current `max_row`. NB this may well not be the last row with cells that contain values.

The following should work for you:

```
match = re.findall(pattern, inputfile.read())
if match:
    for tuple in match:
        ws.append(tuple)
```

Comment: Thank you both for your great answers; they both work! However, between aishenghuomeidaoli's 1st solution and CharlieClark's solution, which would be the best to implement, especially if the input file can become as large as thousands of matches? Is there a choice that is better in terms of memory management and other factors or are they both are exactly the same and thus could use either one effectively? Is there one that could possibly break down in unusual circumstances? Thanks!

Comment: There is no difference but my suggestion will also work with `write-only` mode whereas the other one won't.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define count variable as global variable.

```
row = 2
match = re.findall(pattern, inputfile.read())
if match:
    for tuple in match:
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value = tuple[0]
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value = tuple[1]
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value = tuple[2]
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=4).value = tuple[3]
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=5).value = tuple[4]
        row += 1

# now row equals to 2 + len(match)
match_2 = re.findall(pattern_2, inputfile.read())
if match_2:
    for tuple in match_2:
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value = tuple[0]
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value = tuple[1]
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value = tuple[2]
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=4).value = tuple[3]
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=5).value = tuple[4]
        row += 1
```

This will work, however there's a lot of repeated code.

```
import itertools


def insert(patterns, inputfile, sheet, row=2):
    """insert matches into worksheet 

    :param patterns: pattern list e.g. [r'\d+', r'[a-z]*']
    :param inputfile: file to match
    :param sheet: worksheet
    :param row: start row
    :return:
    """
    match = itertools.chain(filter(lambda x: x, map(lambda x: re.findall(re.compile(x), inputfile.read()), patterns)))
    for r in match:
        for column in range(5):
            sheet(row=row, column=column+1).value = r[column]
            row += 1
```

Comment: Thank you both for your great answers; they both work! However, between aishenghuomeidaoli's 1st solution and CharlieClark's solution, which would be the best to implement, especially if the input file can become as large as thousands of matches? Is there a choice that is better in terms of memory management and other factors or are they both are exactly the same and thus could use either one effectively? Is there one that could possibly break down in unusual circumstances? Thanks!